# Pass an function pointer to ATL member function

Tags: c++, atl

I created an ATL DLL library project`IShape` via vs2019's ATL project wizard, then add an simple ATL project called`ICircle` into this library(pepole should understand what i say if you have the expirences of atl programming). There is a pulibc function `DoSomething` could be called by the client(here, client is the codes which call the DLL public function through COM).

As you known, if you add some function into interface through the project wizard, then you can see that there's no inner types for function pointer(default are BSTR, IDispath*,...,and so on, you can find them in visual studio).In c++, i can pass an function pointer to an function like this:

```
typedef void (*PFN)();
void TestPFN(PFN pfn){
    // something else
}
```

But i couldn't perform this directly in COM. So, what should i do if i want to pass the function pointer to an ATL function?

Comment: I know ATL, and COM, extremely well (drank a lot of beer with CB at many conferences), and for the life of me I couldn't dissect what you're actually trying to ask. I *think* you're asking how you can provide a callable function to a COM method as an argument. The stock COM way of doing that is... not to do that. Rather, your client provides an implementation of an *interface* (that you design for this purpose), and provide a pointer to that interface (much the same way you would provide an IUnknown* or IDispatch*, etc).

Comment: @WhozCraig yes, you are right.Thousands of thanks!